# Having an error regarding a node basedir while installing a ELKstack cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, logstash

My chef-client run fails to finish running the recipe on my test node.  It gives an error upon failure; here is the final output on my Ubuntu workstation:

```
Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/elkstack/recipes/single.rb

undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/elkstack/recipes/logstash.rb:22:in 'from_file'
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/elkstack/recipes/single.rb:14:in 'from_file'
```

This is the line that is causing the error, I'm not sure where to start in troubleshooting the attribute:

```
>> directory node['logstash']['instance_default']['basedir'] do
  owner node['logstash']['instance_default']['user']
  group node['logstash']['instance_default']['group']
  mode '0755'
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error means that either `node['logstash']` or `node['logstash']['instance_default']` are not set. In Ruby, when you request a non-existent key from a Hash you get back nil. Normally this kind of thing should have defaults set in the cookbook's attributes file. Check that your dependencies look correct.

Comment: The berks and knife commands both run without complaints.  I had the same problem with another cookbook (kibana), seperate parts of the ELK stack.  Can I print these attributes to the console?  Thanks again.

Comment: Sure a line like this above the erroring resource: log node['logstash'].inspect

Comment: Hmm. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to incorporate that line into my recipe.  It doesnt output anything at the moment.  Should I look in a log file somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You're using an old version of the logstash cookbook, or you're using some other logstash cookbook. I'd recommend ensuring you have a logstash entry in your Berksfile (as the logstash cookbook being used, while the most popular in the chef community, is not uploaded to Supermarket due someone else having taken the name).

FWIW, this item item 2 under [Things You Should Know](https://github.com/rackspace-cookbooks/elkstack#things-you-should-know) on project's main documentation.